# How to output blob data (not image) from mysql to php?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, blob

I am trying to output encrypted data stored in a table in a BLOB format, but it's not working. I inserted it using prepared statements, and when I checked on the mysql command line client, it showed the entry has been recorded, but the blob fields are empty, and every other field has some value. Also, the `blob` field must not be null, as I have specified it while table creation, so I considered that the command line cannot show the blob field data.

So using php, I have tried to return a `base64_encode` value of the `blob` field, but it didn't help. It's still empty. What do I do?

P.S.: It's not an image, it's encrypted text with AES-256.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO data_store (eid,  ekey, ecipher) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
if($stmt->bind_param("sbb", $eid, $ekey, $ecipher)) {
echo "Successful";

}

// set parameters and execute
$eid=$postedID;
$ekey=$postedKey;
$ecipher=$postedCipher;

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

After that I tried to return the BLOB value encoding it, but it returns nothing whereas the value of id which is a string does show up. How do I solve this? I need to encrypt the data and later decrypt it plaintext for the website.

How do I achieve this?
Thanks a lot.

P.S.: I haven't tried decrypting yet, I need the encrypted value first, so suggesting to decrypt it first won't be a very helpful one.

The table looks like this-

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| eid         | varchar(255)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| ekey        | blob                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ecipher     | blob                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: What's the schema for this table? `SHOW CREATE TABLE` will provide details. How much data are you trying to save into that column?

Comment: I have given a table description above.

Comment: Keep in mind `BLOB` only holds 65KB of data. If you need more, you need a `LONGBLOB`.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that $ekey and $ecipher might have been empty when you did the insert? Empty string "" is not null.

Comment: No, I think I found the problem. The variables weren't empty

Comment: Why are you storing the key next to the ciphertext?

Comment: The key is encrypted itself. @ScottArciszewski

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved when I changed the parameters to `string` "s", this seems to work correctly since the variables I held the data into were strings, so it fits in.

So the corrected code is:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO data_store (eid,  ekey, ecipher) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
if($stmt->bind_param("sss", $eid, $ekey, $ecipher)) {
echo "Successful";
```

I am not saying this is a perfect solution, but it seems to solve my problem for now, I would be extremely helped if someone presents a way of using the `blob` in php instead of `string`. Thank you.

Comment: Weird. The docs say that b should work for blobs. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Exactly, that's why I placed '`b`' in the first place and the record seemed empty. String seems to be working fine now, but I think since it has `b` for blobs, there must be a good reason for it, I would like to know how to do that. @Phil_1984_

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `b` tells mysqli to send the data in separate packets to the server.

[Documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

However, what the documentation fails to detail is how you should specify the packet data.  One would assume, like the other types, you should just set up a referenced variable containing the data.  It turns out you need to use [send_long_data](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php)

With this function you actually have control over each chunk of data, so it's up to you to make sure you don't send a packet too large for your server to handle.

Try something like this

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO data_store (eid,  ekey, ecipher) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

//Initialise variables
$eid = $postedID;
$ekey = NULL;
$ecipher = NULL;

if($stmt->bind_param("sbb", $eid, $ekey, $ecipher)) {

    // Send blobs
    $ekey_chunks = str_split($postedKey, 8192);
    foreach ($ekey_chunks as $chunk) {
        $stmt->send_long_data(1, $chunk);
    }

    $ecipher_chunks = str_split($postedCipher, 8192);
    foreach ($ecipher_chunks as $chunk) {
        $stmt->send_long_data(2, $chunk);
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}

$conn->close();
```

Source [this blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/php_s_mysqli_extension_storing)

Comment: I am having problems with the packet size, how do I send it repeatedly according to my needs?

Comment: The foreach loops in that code should automatically send your chunked data in 8K packets.  This should be small enough for the default setting of 1MB.

Comment: I have my `max_packet` size set to 1024 MB, and it doesn't send my packets automatically, the data when output was incomplete.

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but i added the source at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I think the `str_split` is the wrong function to use here.